# How to configure Twig to automatically escape data inside double curly braces?

Tags: php, twig

I am using Twig **without** Symfony.

I have configured an instance of Twig, this way:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, [
    'autoescape' => 'html',
    'cache' => false,
]);
```

However, in my template, I have many output variables in many different places.
To escape the data, I have to write:

```
{{ var1 | e }}
{{ var2 | e }}
..
{{ varN | e }}
```

without escape filter `| e` the data is not automatically escaped despite I've configured a Twig instance to do that.

So, my question is, how should I confiure Twig, so all my outputs inside double curly braces would be automatically escaped, using html strategy?

If I need to write unescaped data, I will use `{{ varX | raw }}`

Comment: Would using the `{% autoescape %}` tag be sufficient?  [Twig docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/autoescape.html).

Comment: No. I don't want to use any other tags. What is the diffrence, if I will apply the filters in every place, lol.

Comment: Because you can just put that tag once, wrapping everything.  Instead of using the filter for every output.

Comment: See, my contents are mixed. There are parts that shouldn't be escaped and parts that should. I don't need to escape all the template. But some definite vaibles, which count could be large.

Comment: So you would just do exactly what you said and use `{{ varX | raw }}` when outputting something that shouldn't be escaped.  Wrapping the entire template in and `{% autoescape %}` wouldn't be any different than somehow having the engine default to auto-escape.  You'd still have to manually un-escape anything that you didn't want escaped.

Comment: There are two problems in this case. 1) I have to put {% autoescape %} in every template. 2) Why the initial configuration is required if the {% autoescape %} tag is working without it ?

Comment: html escaping is the default behavior.  You really shouldn't have to explicitly set it.  Perhaps you should provide some of your actual code with sample input and the resulting output to show where you are seeing it _not_ being escaped by default (without setting it in the constructor)